# Why is just $0$ extreme point? v22

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

We have $f:R\rightarrow R,\:f\left(x\right)=x^3-3x+2$ and we need to find extreme points for $g:R\rightarrow R\:,\:g\left(x\right)=\int _0^{x^2}\:f\left(t\right)e^tdt$.

Here is all my steps: $g'\left(x\right)=2x\cdot e^{x^2}\cdot \left(x^2+2\right)\left(x-1\right)^2$, $g'\left(x\right)=0\:\:\rightarrow \:\:x=\left\{-1,\:0,\:1\right\}$. But in my book the extreme point is just $0$, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the function to have an extremum at a certain point $x_0$, it is not sufficient that $f'(x_0)=0$.

What is sufficient is that $f'(x)$ alternates signs in a neighborhood of $x_0$, that is $f'(x)<0$ when $x_0-\epsilon<x<x_0$ and $f'(x)>0$ when $x_0<x<x_0+\epsilon$ or vice versa depending on the nature of the extremum.

As you can see, when $x>0$, $g'(x)>0$, when $x<0$, $g(x)<0$. However, as you can easily verify, the derivative doesn't behave that way (by changing signs) at $-1$ or $1$, and thus they are not extrema.

For intuition, consider the function $x^3$. The derivative at $0$ is $0$ but since there is no neighborhood of $0$ in which the derivative alternates signs, there is no extrema there. Graph it if you want to make sure.